# pandas DataFrame create 15minute overlapping intervals

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

I have a pandas DataFrame (df), with the following columns:
    ts_unix, val1, val2
[image: DataFrame data at every minute]

I want to add a new column called "15min_interval" , each interval is a 15 minute window starting at every minute. All the rows within an interval will have the same interval in their interval column (i.e. the first 15 rows have the same interval values):

[image]

I have tried the brute-force method of looping through the 15min_interval values and slicing the df for Ts_unix between each interval, concatenating all the DataFrames and create the df_15min. This takes too long to process.

I also tried creating a date_time column and using floor(15min) but this method creates non-overlapping 15min windows and rounds the starting value to the first 15 minute in the hour. Doesn't work!

I want a faster method of creating overlapping 15-min intervals (overlap at every minute)

Comment: I'm having a hard time following your logic here. Why does the interval change on line 15? Also, copy and paste your code as text, not picture. `df.to_clipboard(False)` will copy a formatted version of your dataframe to the clipboard, which you can paste into your question

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the cleanest solution, but:

```
In [1]: mins = pd.date_range(start='2019-06-29 07:10', end='2019-10-26 00:00', freq='min')
        unix_list = [int(ts.timestamp()) for ts in mins]
        df = pd.DataFrame({'ts_unix': unix_list, 'val1': np.random.random(len(unix_list)),
               'val2': np.random.random(len(unix_list))})
        df['ts_unix'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ts_unix'], unit='s')

        series_15mins = df.set_index('ts_unix', drop=True).resample('15min', loffset=datetime.timedelta(minutes=10)).sum().reset_index().ts_unix
        intervals = list()
        for j in series_15mins.index:
            if j > 0:
                intervals.append(15*[(int(series_15mins.loc[j-1].timestamp()), int(series_15mins.loc[j].timestamp()))])

        intervals = np.array(intervals).reshape(15*len(intervals), 2)
        intervals = intervals[:df.shape[0], :]
        df['15min_interval'] = list(intervals)
        df['ts_unix'] = df['ts_unix'].astype(np.int64)//10**9
```

Which results in:

```
In [2]: df.head(20)
Out[2]:     ts_unix     val1        val2        15min_interval
        0   1561792200  0.497049    0.296606    [1561792200, 1561793100]
        1   1561792260  0.789830    0.132583    [1561792200, 1561793100]
        2   1561792320  0.152093    0.869951    [1561792200, 1561793100]
        3   1561792380  0.631848    0.012687    [1561792200, 1561793100]
        4   1561792440  0.363599    0.685802    [1561792200, 1561793100]
        5   1561792500  0.678252    0.988140    [1561792200, 1561793100]
        6   1561792560  0.627432    0.502722    [1561792200, 1561793100]
        7   1561792620  0.860156    0.414428    [1561792200, 1561793100]
        8   1561792680  0.342857    0.686593    [1561792200, 1561793100]
        9   1561792740  0.004300    0.345949    [1561792200, 1561793100]
        10  1561792800  0.359219    0.178324    [1561792200, 1561793100]
        11  1561792860  0.818282    0.673142    [1561792200, 1561793100]
        12  1561792920  0.396736    0.642892    [1561792200, 1561793100]
        13  1561792980  0.022025    0.901829    [1561792200, 1561793100]
        14  1561793040  0.185680    0.158434    [1561792200, 1561793100]
        15  1561793100  0.813750    0.941224    [1561793100, 1561794000]
        16  1561793160  0.706645    0.504383    [1561793100, 1561794000]
        17  1561793220  0.844269    0.644725    [1561793100, 1561794000]
        18  1561793280  0.604586    0.043472    [1561793100, 1561794000]
        19  1561793340  0.174518    0.577738    [1561793100, 1561794000]
```

**Edit:**
Fifteen minute intervals starting every hour:

```
In [1]: mins = pd.date_range(start='2019-06-29 07:10', end='2019-10-26 00:00', freq='min')
        unix_list = [int(ts.timestamp()) for ts in mins]
        df = pd.DataFrame({'ts_unix': unix_list, 'val1': np.random.random(len(unix_list)), 'val2': np.random.random(len(unix_list))})
        df['15min_interval'] = [*zip(df.ts_unix, df.ts_unix+900)]
Out[1]:        ts_unix      val1        val2              15min_interval
        0   1561792200  0.945755    0.334230    (1561792200, 1561793100)
        1   1561792260  0.044156    0.851238    (1561792260, 1561793160)
        2   1561792320  0.924516    0.276829    (1561792320, 1561793220)
        3   1561792380  0.383580    0.237742    (1561792380, 1561793280)
        4   1561792440  0.782808    0.808183    (1561792440, 1561793340)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. However this is not what I am looking for. The intervals in your example are not overlapping intervals. the correct intervals are the followings: [(1561792200, 1561793100), (1561792260, 1561793160), (1561792310, 1561793220)...] (15-minute window created at "every minute") . so if the size of the dataframe df before adding the "15-min_interval" column was (14228,3) , after adding the interval column it will be (213315, 4). Thanks!

Comment: Okay, I see. See my edited answer now. I don't understand how you get a dataframe with 213315 rows this way though? If you have an interval starting every minute of the original df, the resulting df will be the same shape.